# Converter ficheiro para txt

Tags: php, upload

Tive a procura na net mas não encontrei nada relativamente a fazer *upload* de um ficheiro qualquer e converte-lo para `txt` para depois fazer um pesquisa ao texto que tiver dentro e obter resultados.

Alguém sabe como isso se faz o que possa deixar uns *links* para eu estudar o caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converter arquivos binários para `.txt` não vai fazer uma busca funcionar, cada arquivo possui seu próprio formato.

Para cada tipo de arquivo você terá que usar um método para extrair os dados e salva-los em um `.txt`, alguns exemplo:

1. XML use http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php

   Exemplo:

   ```
   //Caminho que o seu arquivo xml foi salvo
   $xml = file_get_contents('arquivo.xml');
   $frases = array();

   $dom = new DOMDocument;
   $dom->loadXML($xml);
   $books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
   foreach ($books as $book) {
       $frases[] = $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
   }

   //Salve o $vetor em um txt, assim:
   file_put_contents('arquivo.xml.txt', implode(' ', $frases));
   ```
2. CSV use http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php

   ```
   //Caminho que o seu arquivo xml foi salvo
   $handle = fopen ("arquivo.csv", "r");
   $frases = array();
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
       $frases = array_merge($frases, $data);
   }
   fclose ($handle);

   file_put_contents('arquivo.csv.txt', implode(' ', $frases));
   ```
3. XLS provavelmente terá que usar uma biblioteca pra facilitar como https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ ou http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Estes são apenas alguns exemplos, para cada formato que você implementar na sua aplicação você terá que usar um novo script.

Acredito que não exista solução "mágica" pronta para isto, você terá que pegar o que existe e criar uma aplicação em base disto.

Pra fazer a consulta, vamos supor que você salvou todos `.txt` em uma pasta, então você deverá fazer uma busca semelhante a isto:

```
$consulta = 'Palavra';
$arquivos = array();

if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        if (is_file($dir . $file)) {
            $data = file_get_contents($dir . $file);
            if (stripos($data, $consulta) !== false) {
                 $arquivos[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dh);
}

echo 'A consulta "', $consulta, '" encontrou ', count($arquivos), ': ', implode(', ', $arquivos);
```

Comment: E se for uma imagem vai precisar fazer OCR. E se for PDF vai precisar (...). E se for (...) vai precisar (...).

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas se você quer a relação de ficheiros listadas em um arquivo txt, use o seguinte comando:

```
exec( "dir $diretorio /s > $NomeArquivo.txt" );
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço